# iText PDF add text in absolute position on top of the 1st page

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I have a script that creates a PDF file and writes contents to it. After the execution is complete I need to write the status (fail, success) to the PDF, but the status should be on the top of the page. So the solution I came up with is to use absolute positioned text. Below is my code for the same

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.SaveState();
cb.BeginText();
cb.MoveText(700, 30);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
cb.ShowText("My status");
cb.EndText();
cb.RestoreState();
```

But as the PDF creates multiple pages, this is added to the last page of the PDF. How can I add it to the 1st page??

Also is there a way to calculate the top coordinates of the page, ie the top-left coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

iText was written with internet applications in mind. It was designed to flush content from memory as soon as possible: if a page is finished, that page is sent to the `OutputStream` and there is no way to return to that page.

That doesn't mean your requirement is impossible. PDF has a concept known as *Form XObject*. In iText, this concept is implemented under the name `PdfTemplate`. Such a `PdfTemplate` is a rectangular canvas with a fixed size that can be added to a page without being part of that page.

An example should clarify what that means. Please take a look at the [WriteOnFirstPage](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/columntext/WriteOnFirstPage) example. In this example, we create a `PdfTemplate` like this:

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
PdfTemplate message = cb.createTemplate(523, 50);
```

This `message` object refers to a Form XObject. It is a piece of content that is external to the page content.

We wrap the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object. By doing so, we can add the Form XObject to the document just like any other object:

```
Image header = Image.getInstance(message);
document.add(header);
```

Now we can add as much data as we want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    document.add(new Paragraph("test"));
}
```

Adding 100 "test" lines will cause iText to create 3 pages. Once we're on page 3, we no longer have access to page 1, but we can still write content to the `message` object:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(message);
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(0, 0, 523, 50));
ct.addElement(
    new Paragraph(
        String.format("There are %s pages in this document", writer.getPageNumber())));
ct.go();
```

If you check the resulting PDF [write_on_first_page.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/write_on_first_page.pdf), you'll notice that the text we've added last is indeed on the first page.